# Function declaration for moving std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics

There are few good answers for passing shared pointer by value vs reference. However, I didn't find an answer on best practice for 'moving' a shared pointer.

I have function that has a shared pointer to an object, that it doesn't want to hold on to. And as I understand it, moving it is the best option in terms of performance, since we can skip the step of increasing and then immediately decreasing ref count. However, what's not clear to me, if at all there's a difference between these 2 declarations :

Caller function

```
foo(std::move(sourcePtr));
```

Should the declaration be

Option 1

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<X> x);
```

Or Option 2

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<X>&& x);
```

Comment: It depends on what the function does with the `shared_ptr`. For example, if the function does nothing, in the first case, the caller's `shared_ptr` is moved from, in the second it isn't.

Comment: Does the function just use the pointed to object? Or does it modify the hared_ptr` itself?

Comment: It just holds a strong ref, and does not modify the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that `std::move` doesn't actually perform *move* on the object, it just converts the object to an rvalue (xvalue).

Then for the 1st case, the parameter `x` will be move-constructed from `sourcePtr`. After that `sourcePtr`'s managed pointer would be null.

For the 2nd case, no `std::shared_ptr` being constructed; `x` is an rvalue-reference and bound to `sourcePtr`. Then what would happen depends on the implementation of `foo()`, and `sourcePtr` won't be moved from until you do it inside `foo()` via `x`, e.g. `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x);`.

Comment: Yeah, I do have a member variable (foo() is in a different class) which does this - `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x);` So Option 1 and then `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x)`  is the best option right, given I don't intend to modify the object?

Comment: @idok What do you mean `don't modify the object`? When go with option1 and `foo(std::move(sourcePtr));`, `sourcePtr` will be moved from and then points to a null pointer. Is it OK?

Comment: Yea the calling method does not require the pointer. So it's okay if sourcePtr is null. Isn't that the whole point of 'move' though? Indicating that the calling method has no use for it, and therefore would like to move it.

Comment: @idok Suppose the two options have the same implementation including `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x);`, then for the option1 move will be performed twice, i.e. when `sourcePtr` passed to `foo` and `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x);`. For option2 move will be performed once, i.e. when `std::shared_ptr<X> new_x = std::move(x);`. This is a different point.